# Error trying to map ImmutableDictionary with AutoMapper

Tags: c#, .net, automapper, immutable-collections

I want to map a POCO into an `ImmutableDictionary<string, object>` and Automapper is raising an exception because the `Add` operation is not supported in `ImmutableDictionary`.

The POCO object is in a property called `Data` in the source type that gets mapped to the `DataBag` property in the destination. The type of the `Data` is not known at this time.

I'm using this mapping:

```
var t = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
                    cfg.CreateMap(@event.GetType(), typeof(StoredEvent))
                       .ForMember("DataBag", opt => opt.MapFrom("Data")));
```

and getting this error:

```
Mapping types:
Dictionary`2 -> ImmutableDictionary`2
System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] -> System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

Destination path:
StoredEvent.DataBag.DataBag.DataBag
```

To solve this I tried to use a custom resolver:

```
public class ImmutableDictionaryResolver : IValueResolver
{
    public ResolutionResult Resolve(ResolutionResult source)
    {
        var dictionary = Mapper.Map<Dictionary<string, object>>(source.Value);
        return source.New(dictionary.ToImmutableDictionary());
    }
}
```

With this mapping:

```
var t = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            cfg.CreateMap(@event.GetType(), typeof(StoredEvent))
            .ForMember(nameof(StoredEvent.DataBag), opt => 
              opt.ResolveUsing<ImmutableDictionaryResolver>().FromMember("Data")));
```

But I'm still getting the same error. In the second instance, it complaints with this:

```
Mapping types:
ImmutableDictionary`2 -> ImmutableDictionary`2
System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]] -> System.Collections.Immutable.ImmutableDictionary`2[[System.String, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089],[System.Object, mscorlib, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089]]

Destination path:
StoredEvent.DataBag.DataBag
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using `ForMember` try to use `ConstructUsing` so you can give it a value for your immutable object.

```
var t = new MapperConfiguration(cfg =>
            cfg.CreateMap(@event.GetType(), typeof(StoredEvent))
            .ConstructUsing(x => new ImmutableDictionaryResolver(...)));
```